# Discord.py - Message.content to a TextChannel

Tags: discord.py

I have setup the bot asks a couple questions. One of them is about a channel. How do I transform the `message.content` into a channel?

Script:

```
ChannelA = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

channel = self.client.get_channel(ChannelA.content)

await ChannelA.delete()

#Continues with some more questions
```

From the `ChannelA.content` you get a string but I want if, for example,  a person mentions the channel it will use this channel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a channel is mentioned it will return: `<#channelID>` and because you can't force it to return the object type of discord.TextChannel, I believe your best bet would to be do something like this:

```
ChannelA = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

channel_id = int(ChannelA.content[2:-1])

channel = self.client.get_channel(channel_id)

await channel.delete()

#Continues with some more questions
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion worked perfect for where I was looking for!